# Using Saved Video from Camera Roll with AVRURLAsset - initWithURL - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, video

I have the following code which saves a UIImage or video which has been selected from the camera roll.

```
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
    introImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    //Unhide our UIImage Preview and insert our chosen Video or Intro.
    selectIntroButton.hidden = YES;
    selectedIntro.hidden = NO;
    cancelIntroChoiceButton.hidden = NO;
    selectedIntro.image = introImage;
}
else if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie])
{

    //Create variable for video.

    AVURLAsset *asset=[[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:??? options:nil];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset];
    generator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform=TRUE;
    [asset release];
    CMTime thumbTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0,30);
```

My question is how do I feed the selected video into AVURLAssset initWithURL ? What type of object is [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] returning ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get at the asset's URL with the `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL` key.

`[[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL]]`